# how to set old password in update form in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I using user form in that form when user enter all the entry this entry insert into the database but I facing one problem
The problem is that when user go for update his details that time user not change his password so password value set the null value and inserted into the database so my question is how to set user old password into password field
I can't understand how to set old my code is below this my update form password field

```
 <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:', array('class'=>'col-md-2 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want change in this field to set old password in this field and when user again update his form that password value not be null insert into the database.

Comment: You don't, simply don't pass `password` field when you update.

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: Don't be lazy, all you have to do is check if `! is_null(Input::get('password))`. If it's `null` then don't update the password if it isn't update it. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `password` the validation rule:

```
required
```

also it would be good if you use an extra input named `password_confirmation` and you add to the `password` named field the `confirmed` validation rule.

Comment: Of course not. If you use `type="password"` you are ok and `Form::password()` does exactly that for you. Of course you won't use  value like `value="{{ Input::old('password', $user->password) }}"` for the password field so every time page gets refreshed the password field will stay empty. There is an alternative option that on profile update page you don't offer password update option only on a password reset page you do so. But there you should also do as i told you above for password fields. Do those make sense to you?

Comment: It was ironic, you know. `type=password` protects you from.. nothing at all, and why in the world you would ever want to pass encrypted password back to the user...

Comment: Who told to pass the password back to the user? I ve said be careful never do that with old password input. It has to be left blank when user visits the update form or when gets redirected back with faulty inputs and errors. User has to re-enter always the password when page gets refreshed. This is why if the password field is provided he has either to add a required rule for password either to omit password reset either not update db password when it is left blank. Now he has it there without validation rules and when user submits the form then db is updated with a null password which iswrong

Comment: And how exactly adding `required` will solve his problem? `required` will force the user to change his password (or repeat it) every time he wants to update his personal information. What he's asking is how to preserve the user's password if he doesn't input anything in the `password` field, which will involve some extra logic in his controller since Laravel doesn't have a out-of-the-box solution for this.

Comment: Ok, if he then wants that, he can omit password and offer password's change on a password reset page, else if he still wants it to be there he has to check `Input::get('password')` value and then if its value is set only then he should update password's value in his db. But this is not the most preferable option i suppose, a password reset page is a better one in my opinion.